# Bootstrap 4.5 Dropdown appearing as multiple links on iOS

Tags: css, ios, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I try to load a dropdown list in a Bootstrap navbar on an ASP.NET page, the desktop version of the list loads exactly as it appears on the [official navbar documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/), but not when loading the same page on an iPad Air 2 with iOS 13.3.1. Instead of loading the listed items in a dropdown fashion, they appear below the dropdown menu's name. Just as well, the toggle "hamburger" button appears as a blank button.
[image: The links are separated]

I've heard elsewhere that the link in the list needs to have `href="#"`, but this has already been done, as you will see below:

### Head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, width=device-width, initial scale=1.0" />
<title>Navbar Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="packages/popper.js.1.16.1/content/Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
```

### Body

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="smmaster" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
       <div class="container-sm">
        Navbar Test
       </div>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
       aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" type="button" />
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" />
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="background-color: white;">
         <a href="#" id="btnMain" class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Main</a>
         <div id="ddlMain" runat="server" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnMain">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A link</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another link</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A third and final link</a>
         </div>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </nav>
   </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </div>
</form>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: it seems like the CSS file is not getting properly included in ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `bootstrap.min.css` file is being loaded from a CDN, rather than using a local file. Formatting errors can be resolved simply by retrieving Bootstrap through Nuget and importing the file like so:

```
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```